# Error: "logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))" - in Keras model to Estimator

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, tensorflow-datasets

I am new to ML and trying out Keras models. I wanted to learn about Keras model to `tf.Estimator` and hence pieced together code from various examples. The code has three key parts - first part creates `TFRecord` files by reading a set of images from folder, second part reads from the `TFRecord` files and provides to `input_fn`, third part is the Keras model with VGG16 and a simple fully-connected layer.

While the first two parts of code work properly, I am getting this error -

```
'ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))'
```

while training. As referenced in another similar question's answer, I tried `expand-dim` and even reshape of my `labels` to `(?, 1)`, but that gave me some other error.

I am not sure what is wrong with this code and reason for

```
'ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs (?,))'.
```

Please help identify the mistake and suggest a solution. Thanks in advance. I have copy-pasted my code from notebook below.

---

```
**Cell1 contents**

from random import shuffle
import glob
import sys
import cv2
import numpy as np
#import skimage.io as io
import tensorflow as tf

def _int64_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(int64_list=tf.train.Int64List(value=[value]))
def _bytes_feature(value):
    return tf.train.Feature(bytes_list=tf.train.BytesList(value=[value]))

def load_image(addr):
    # read an image and resize to (224, 224)
    # cv2 load images as BGR, convert it to RGB
    img = cv2.imread(addr)
    if img is None:
        return None
    img = cv2.resize(img, (224, 224), interpolation=cv2.INTER_CUBIC)
    img = cv2.cvtColor(img, cv2.COLOR_BGR2RGB)
    return img

def createDataRecord(out_filename, addrs, labels):
    # open the TFRecords file
    #writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_filename)
    options = tf.python_io.TFRecordOptions(tf.python_io.TFRecordCompressionType.GZIP)
    writer = tf.python_io.TFRecordWriter(out_filename, options=options)

    for i in range(len(addrs)):
        # print how many images are saved every 1000 images
        if not i % 1000:
            print('Train data: {}/{}'.format(i, len(addrs)))
            sys.stdout.flush()
        # Load the image
        img = load_image(addrs[i])

        label = labels[i]

        if img is None:
            continue

        # Create a feature
        feature = {
            'image': _bytes_feature(img.tostring()),
            'label': _int64_feature(label)
        }
        # Create an example protocol buffer
        example = tf.train.Example(features=tf.train.Features(feature=feature))

        # Serialize to string and write on the file
        writer.write(example.SerializeToString())

    writer.close()
    sys.stdout.flush()

**Cell2 contents**

cat_dog_train_path = 'dataset-mix/*/*.jpg'
# read addresses and labels from the 'train' folder
addrs = glob.glob(cat_dog_train_path)
labels = [0 if 'A' in addr else 1 for addr in addrs]  # 0 = A, 1 = B

# to shuffle data
c = list(zip(addrs, labels))
shuffle(c)
addrs, labels = zip(*c)

#print("addrs: " + str(addrs))
#print("labels: " + str(labels))

# Divide the data into 60% train, 20% validation, and 20% test
train_addrs = addrs[0:int(0.6*len(addrs))]
train_labels = labels[0:int(0.6*len(labels))]
val_addrs = addrs[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
val_labels = labels[int(0.6*len(addrs)):int(0.8*len(addrs))]
test_addrs = addrs[int(0.8*len(addrs)):]
test_labels = labels[int(0.8*len(labels)):]

print("train_addrs: " + str(train_addrs))
print("train_labels: " + str(train_labels))

createDataRecord('train-zipped.tfrecords', train_addrs, train_labels)
createDataRecord('val-zipped.tfrecords', val_addrs, val_labels)
createDataRecord('test-zipped.tfrecords', test_addrs, test_labels)

------
**second part**
**Cell3 contents**

import tensorflow as tf
import cv2
import sys
import numpy as np

sess = tf.Session()
sess.run(tf.global_variables_initializer())

def parser(record):
    keys_to_features = {
        "image": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.int64)
    }

    parsed = tf.parse_single_example(record, keys_to_features)
    image = tf.decode_raw(parsed["image"], tf.uint8)
    image = tf.cast(image, tf.float32)
    image = tf.reshape(image, shape=[224, 224, 3])
    label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.int32)

    #return {'image': image}, label
    print("image.shape: " + str(np.shape(image)))
    print("label.shape before: " + str(np.shape(label)) + "; label: " + str(label))

    #label = np.array(label)
    #print("label.shape after making np.array: " + str(np.shape(label)))
    #label = np.expand_dims(label, axis=1)
    #label = np.reshape(label, (-1, 1))
    print("labels1.shape after expand_dims" + str(np.shape(label)))

    return {'vgg16_input': image}, label


def input_fn(filenames=["train-zipped.tfrecords"]):

  #To create a TFRecordDataset to read the compressed files:
  dataset = tf.data.TFRecordDataset(filenames=filenames, compression_type='GZIP', num_parallel_reads=40)

  dataset = dataset.apply(
      tf.contrib.data.shuffle_and_repeat(1024, 1)
  )
  dataset = dataset.apply(
      tf.contrib.data.map_and_batch(parser, 32)
  )
  #dataset = dataset.map(parser, num_parallel_calls=12)
  #dataset = dataset.batch(batch_size=1000)

  #print("dataset: " + str(dataset.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()))

  dataset = dataset.prefetch(buffer_size=2)

  return dataset


def train_input_fn():
    return input_fn(filenames=["train-zipped.tfrecords", "test-zipped.tfrecords"])

def val_input_fn():
    return input_fn(filenames=["val-zipped.tfrecords"])

dat_set = train_input_fn()
item1 = dat_set.make_one_shot_iterator().get_next()[1]
res = sess.run(item1)
print("dataset: " + str(np.shape(res)))

#train_dataset = train_input_fn("train-zipped.tfrecords", "test-zipped.tfrecords")
#val_dataset = val_input_fn("val-zipped.tfrecords")

#print("classes: {0};\n shapes: {1};\n types: {2}\n".format(train_dataset.output_classes, 
#            train_dataset.output_shapes, train_dataset.output_types))

-----------
**third part**
**Cell4 contents**

def make_keras_estimator(): 
    from tensorflow.python.keras.applications.vgg16 import VGG16
    from tensorflow.python.keras import models
    from tensorflow.python.keras import layers
    import os

    conv_base = VGG16(weights='imagenet',
                  include_top=False,
                  input_shape=(224, 224, 3))
    conv_base.trainable = False

    model = models.Sequential()
    model.add(conv_base)
    model.add(layers.Flatten())
    model.add(layers.Dense(256, activation='relu'))
    model.add(layers.Dense(1, activation='sigmoid'))

    model.compile(loss='binary_crossentropy',
                  optimizer=tf.keras.optimizers.RMSprop(lr=2e-5),
                  metrics=['acc'])

    model_dir = os.path.join(os.getcwd(), "model-keras-mix")
    os.makedirs(model_dir, exist_ok=True)
    print("model_dir: ",model_dir)
    model.summary()

    print("input_names" + str(model.input_names ))

    model_est = tf.keras.estimator.model_to_estimator(keras_model=model,
                                                        model_dir=model_dir)
    return model_est

**Cell5 contents**
model_keras = make_keras_estimator()

train_spec = tf.estimator.TrainSpec(input_fn=train_input_fn, max_steps=10)
eval_spec = tf.estimator.EvalSpec(input_fn=val_input_fn)

import time
start_time = time.time()
tf.estimator.train_and_evaluate(model_keras, train_spec, eval_spec)
print("--- %s seconds ---" % (time.time() - start_time))
```

Comment: Have you tried reshaping the logits at the end of your inference?   This is quite an interesting approach since you are doing tf input-> Keras inference -> tf execution. Can you keep me updated if it works? I have done something similar a while back but I have used Keras for model execution.  You can read about this here : https://medium.com/p/5464f9836c36?source=linkShare-b7d1e0266b3-1537422002

Comment: Hi @Smokrow, thanks for responding with suggestion and a pointer. Let me check them and update.

Comment: Hi @Smokrow, regarding your suggestion 'reshaping logits at the end of inference' - because my model is defined using Keras, I don't get to shape / reshape the logits. So, not sure how I can reshape logits. if you know how to do it please share

Comment: Maybe try reshaping your labels to [?].

Comment: I did try reshaping label, as mentioned earlier. But I get this error: TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'Cast_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>

Comment: BTW, if I replace Keras model in the above code with tensorflow model, then the code works without error (training of model happens without error).

Comment: Oh Crazy.  I did not know that you can do that.  Can you post your model creation?

Comment: @Smokrow, I tried the approach described in the article you mentioned ([https://medium.com/@moritzkrger/speeding-up-keras-with-tfrecord-datasets-5464f9836c36]), but that also did not work. Issue with that is, article suggests to pass one hot encoded labels list to Keras model.compile() method. But compile() method throws TypeError `TypeError: ('Expected `target_tensors` to be a list or dict, but got:', <tf.Tensor 'one_hot_2:0' shape=(32, 1) dtype=float32>)`.

Comment: I think you need to throw out the one hot encoder since your last layer has only one output

Comment: yep, tried that too...but no use

Comment: Can you post the stack trace of the type error you get after you reshape the label? That is what the solution to this problem should be.

Comment: Hi @AlexandrePassos, I am in the middle of changing laptops and need to rerun the Notebook to get full stack trace. Will do that once done with setting-up my new laptop. BTW, which TypeError are you are referring to? Asking this as I had mentioned two diff TypeErrors in my earlier comments. Let me know which one of these you are referring to 1.`TypeError: Expected binary or unicode string, got <tf.Tensor 'Cast_1:0' shape=() dtype=int32>` or 2. `TypeError: ('Expected target_tensors` to be a list or dict, but got:', <tf.Tensor 'one_hot_2:0' shape=(32, 1) dtype=float32>)`

Comment: Hey. I saw your comment on medium.  I think it is easier to discuss this topic here.  Is the question still relevant?

Comment: Yep, question is still relevant as I could not get the code working as suggested in that article in medium. I haven't received any resolution from the author yet. BTW, as mentioned in my earlier comment, I am in between setting-up my new laptop and hence unable to share full stack trace. give me a day or two for the same.

Answer (score 0):

I think the error message indicates the label should be of shape (1,) instead of just a scalar.

> 'ValueError: logits and labels must have the same shape ((?, 1) vs
>   (?,))'

My suggested solution is to add a '1' in the feature spec for 'label'.

```
def parser(record):
    keys_to_features = {
        "image": tf.FixedLenFeature([], tf.string),
        "label": tf.FixedLenFeature([1], tf.int64)  # add the 1 in this line
    }
    ......
```

In addition, since the model output (sigmoid) is float32, I think you should cast label to float32 instead of int32.

```
    label = tf.cast(parsed["label"], tf.float32)
```